# How to convert a number always to be negative?

Tags: java

`Math.abs()` converts any number to positive. Is there also a function (that I might be missing) that supports the other way around: convert any number (no matter of sign) to a negative number?

The only thing I could imagine is:
`Math.abs(number) * -1`

Comment: you can do it manually !

Comment: Do you mean something like `-1 * Math.abs()`?

Comment: yes you just answered ur question in the edit :D

Comment: `number*(-1);` No library required

Comment: ok thought there might be a "better" way, but obviously that's the way to go according to your comments.

Comment: @Apurva:  If `number` is negative, now it's positive.

Comment: @Makoto yes, you are right, it should be Math.abs()*(-1) as others have suggested

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can just put `-` in front of the `abs`, such as this `-Math.abs()`

Comment: Weird. I would have expected compiler errors in certain circumstances, but this seems to work very nicely.

Answer (score 11):

In kotlin you can use unaryMinus

```
input = input.unaryMinus()
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/unary-minus.html

Comment: This will return negative value only if the input value is positive: https://pl.kotl.in/xFKL1c2o3 , but question was "How to convert a number always to be negative?"

Answer (score 0):

Just as alternative solution you could use something like

```
int y = x < 0 ? x : -x;
```

but `- abs(x)` is more readable IMO.